# AWS cloud: SSH of an AMI instance issue in Prod

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, redhat

I am facing a very minor isue and not able to figure it out :(

I have 2 AWS accounts(Preprod and Prod)

First AWS A/c is a preprod account where I have created a jumphost(preprod_Server1  and login to  instance(i.e preprod_Server2 )

```
preprod_Server1>> ssh vin@preprod_Server2  (This works fine,password less SSH)
```

Now IN second AWS account i.e PROD

I have created a  server_prod1 (jumphost ) and I have taken an AMI of preprod_Server2.

I have copied id_rsa public key in authorised file of preprod_Server2 and then taken the AMI image of it.
Now I launch an instance with an AMI of preprod_Server2
when I login from server_prod1  it's not allowing me.

```
prod_Server1>> ssh vin@preprod_Server2  ( I get permission denied)

Note: only pem file is different in preprod and prod account is that an issue.
```

I am not aware of the root credentials of preprod_Server2.

In prod server I am able to login to other instance only AMI of preprod_Server2 is giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

the key is excluded from the AMI when you built it. 
Another key is injected into the machine when you launch it (everytime you launch an EC2 machine you have to specify the key).

Answer (score 0):

This works by copying the id_rsa publickey of prod_Server1 to authorised keys file in preprod_Server2. And then take the AMI of preprod_Server2.

```
prod_Server1>> ssh vin@preprod_Server2 (This works)
```

Note : somehow Initially when I copied the keys there was an extra space which resulted in problem.